# "an internal error has occurred" when testing a Google Database Migration Service Job

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am attempting to migrate a cloud sql postgres database to a new instance using the  [Database Migration Service](https://cloud.google.com/database-migration/docs/overview).

### Basic configuration:

- Source database engine: Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL
- Destination database engine: Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL
- Type: Continuous
- Region: us-central1
- Connectivity method: VPC peering

When clicking the "Test Job" button, I was getting detailed errors as to which privileges were still required (meaning the Job was able to connect to my database in some way in order to read database names and tables names)

After having granted the required privileges I attempted to "Test Job" again.
I am now getting, the error:
[Test unsuccessful: an internal error has occurred](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hADu5.png)

I have left it overnight in the hope that this mysterious internal error might "fix itself", but to no avail.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: your connection method you list as VPC-peering. What network is the source database in, and what network are you trying to run the DMS migration to? Are they the same network?